# How to dynamically write $index as part of ng-model name?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use $index in an ng-repeat to dynamically add an index to my ng-model.  I can't figure out how to type it so it shows up right.

This is the closest I've gotten, except the single quotes still show up:

```
        <tr ng-model="arrayOfArrays" ng-repeat="x in exes">
            <th>{{x}}</th>
            <td ng-model="arrayOfArrays['{{$index}}'][0]">{{}}</td>
            <td ng-model="arrayOfArrays['{{$index}}'][1]">{{}}</td>
            <td ng-model="arrayOfArrays['{{$index}}'][2]">{{}}</td>
        </tr>
```

What I want the end result to be:

```
        <tr ng-repeat="x in exes">
            <th>{{x}}</th>
            <td ng-model="arrayOfArrays[0][0]">{{}}</td>
            <td ng-model="arrayOfArrays[1][1]">{{}}</td>
            <td ng-model="arrayOfArrays[2][2]">{{}}</td>
        </tr>
```

I just want to know how to write the ng-model name so that the incrementing value of $index is included as part of the ng-model name. The only way I am getting the value to appear is by using extra single quotes that appear to become part of the ng-model name.

Comment: why would you need `ng-model` for a `<td>` or `<tr>` in the first place? What are you trying to do? Provide written description since code shown isn't intuitive. `$index` is valid variable without needing `{{}}` ... `arrayOfArrays[$index][0]`

Comment: Remove the `'` thing. Why do you need it?

Comment: Are you  using PHP? Where  are the tags?

Comment: ´ng-model=" 'arrayOfArrays[' +  $index + '][0]' "´

Comment: If using PHP, inside double quotes you can put the curly braces around the entire Multi-dimensional Array. The only time you don't have to use curly braces in double quotes when using an Array in PHP is if it's not Multi-dimensional Array and it's indexes are numeric. Of course, you may also use concatenation to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use

```
ng-repeat="(index, x) in exes"
```

Then index would be incremented with each "x" you go through. Also, you could use :

```
ng-repeat="x in exes track by $index"
```

This should increment $index as you currently have.

Comment: Cool. How do I include the incremented value of $index in the name of the ng-model?  The only way I'm able to see the value is by having extra single quotes somewhere around it, but then they become part of the ng-model name?